# Javascript file in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner with hyperledger. I want to retrieve all data from Asset of Car for do something in javascript file in hyperledger composer. I don't need to input id of asset car one by one. how can i do?

**Model**

```
participant Car identified by participant id{
 o String id
 o String name
}

asset CarAsset identified by id{
 o String id
 o String type
}

transaction CarTransaction{
 --> UserAsset asset
 //what can i do in here?
}
```

**Transaction**

```
function carTransaction(tx){
 //what can i do in here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data of all the cars, you can write a query and use it in a transaction function

query.qry

```
query select Cars {
  description: "Select all cars"
  statement:
      SELECT <your namespace>.Car
}
```

Take a look at this query [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/queries) it might help